# PHP fgetcsv() delimiter ';' not recognized

Tags: php, csv

it seems I have a problem with the ";" delimiter. Here's my csv file:

```
First Name;Last Name;Email;Age
Julie;Brown;julie@example.com;52
Dan;Wong;dan@example.com;19
Tim;Hortons;tim@example.com;27
```

and my PHP code:

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("upload/".$_FILES['fichier']['name'], "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num champs à la ligne $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
fclose($handle);
}
```

and I have this out put:

```
1 champs à la ligne 1: 
First Name;Last Name;Email;Age
1 champs à la ligne 2: 
Julie;Brown;julie@example.com;52
1 champs à la ligne 3: 
Dan;Wong;dan@example.com;19
1 champs à la ligne 4: 
Tim;Hortons;tim@example.com;27
```

instead of something like this when I use the ',' delimiter

```
4 champs à la ligne 1: 
First Name
Last Name
Email
Age
```

Besides, I want to know if it is possible to have various delimiters. Because I want to display csv files uploaded by users and I don't want to force them to use one predetermined delimiter.

Thanks

Comment: updated my answer with example for your second question on using multiple delimiters either defined by the user or by parsing the CSV data row by row.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second parameter is the length, so your fgetcsv should be

```
fgetcsv($handle, 0, ';');
```

Resulting in

```
4 champs à la ligne 1: 

First Name
Last Name
Email
Age
4 champs à la ligne 2: 

Julie
Brown
julie@example.com
52
4 champs à la ligne 3: 

Dan
Wong
dan@example.com
19
4 champs à la ligne 4: 

Tim
Hortons
tim@example.com
27
```

---

As for your second question on variable delimiters. By far the easiest method would allow the user to define which delimiter to use on the upload form, possibly using a select element of acceptable delimiters and then use it when reading the csv.

For Example

```
function filter_delimiter($v) {
    return in_array($v, [',', ';'], true) ? $v : null;
}

//validate $_POST['delimiter'];
$delimiter = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'delimiter', FILTER_CALLBACK, ['options' => 'filter_delimiter']);
if (!$delimiter) {
    $delimiter = ';';
    //optionally redirect to form error message
}
```

Alternatively parse the lines to determine the appropriate delimiter.

```
$filename = "upload/".$_FILES['fichier']['name'];
if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== false) {
    $content = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle);
    //count the delimiters
    $semiColons = substr_count($content, ';');
    $commas = substr_count($content, ',');
    //read each row
    $rows = str_getcsv($content, "\n");
    $rowCount = count($rows);
    $delimiter = null;
    foreach ($rows as $line => $row) {
        //check the delimiters
        if (false === isset($delimiter)) {
            /* 
              determine if the delimiter total divided by the number 
              of rows matches the delimiters found on this row 
              and use it to parse the columns 
            */
            if ($semiColons > 0 && $semiColons / $rowCount === substr_count($row, ';')) {
                $delimiter = ';';
            } elseif ($commas > 0 && $commas / $rowCount === substr_count($row, ',')) {
                $delimiter = ',';
            }
        }
        //read the columns using the detected delimiter 
        //otherwise use a default if a delimiter could not be determined
        $columns = str_getcsv($row, $delimiter ? : ';');
        echo "<p>$rowCount champs à la ligne " . ($line + 1) . "</p>\n";
        foreach ($columns as $column) {
            echo $column . "<br/>\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> array fgetcsv ( resource $handle [, int $length = 0 [, string $delimiter = "," [, string $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape = "\" ]]]] )

[Manual](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.fgetcsv.php)

Second parameter is the length.

```
fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";")
```

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. Do you have a solution for my second question? for instance someone uploads a csv file with ';' delimiter and an other one with ',' delimiter how can I process with this 2 cases? and others cases with other delimiters

Comment: Read the first line and search `;` or `,` and use it after or don't use `fgetcsv` and read the file line by line and use `preg_split('/[;|,]/', $line)`.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at it :)

Answer (score 1):

The function `fgetcsv` contains five parameters. Here is its declaration:

```
fgetcsv(resource, lenght, delimiter, enclosure, escape)
```

This is my resource `file.csv`:

```
"mydata1|mydata2|mydata3|my;data;with;ugly"char;|myprice|etc|etc|
```

In my case, the delimiter is a pipe character `|`. The semicolon is **not** a delimiter. As we have double quotes `"` among the data, we use a single quote character `'` as an enclosure. With no enclosure, the output will be empty.

Here is the source code:

```
$mycsv = fopen("file.csv", "r");

while (($data = fgetcsv($mycsv, 0, "|", "'")) == true) {
   print_r($data);
}
```

Here is the output data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "mydata1
    [1] => mydata2
    [2] => mydata3
    [3] => my;data;with;ugly"char;
    [4] => myprice
    [5] => etc
    [6] => etc
    [7] => 
)
```

You can also look at the following Ideone snippet: https://ideone.com/30OF1K. The `file.csv` file was replaced with `stdin`.